# How to have subscript and superscript in PyQt textedit

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

PyQt text edit does not have a default set vertical alignment property.I want to

know how to have to have subscript and superscript in pyqt text edit

for example when i right H20 I want 2 to be a little smaller and to be at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `QTextBrowser` and the `<sub>` and `<sup>` tags.

```
browser = QTextBrowser()
browser.setHtml("H<sub>2</sub>O")
```

(Code for QApplication initialization etc. not shown)